# Please do not bother me about password mismatches until I've finished typing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-accounts, user-experience, sign-up

When I tried to use the new login page to create a new Stack Exchange account, I found the functionality of the password check very annoying and a bit too aggressive.

As soon as I enter the password field, and start typing, I get a red warning message about the password not being allowed to match my account name

> [image: Obnoxious warning message #1]

Then when I continued typing, the message changed to tell me the password rules a couple of times depending which rule I wasn't following at the time

> [image: Obnoxious warning message #2]
>
> [image: Obnoxious warning message #3]

And then when I finished typing, as soon as I entered the "confirm password" field, I started getting the message about the passwords not matching

> [image: Obnoxious warning message #4]

I realize the old login page had the same functionality, but the small red letters next to the password field are much less annoying than the big red warning message.

> [image: Less obnoxious warning message on old style login page]

---

**Can we make the checking more intelligent or at least tone it down so it isn't as annoying?**

Comment: "Add upper case, numbers, or special characters." Fun fact: you need at least *two* of those things in your password. Have fun figuring out which two.

Comment: Out of curiousity: why do you want another account?

Comment: @user689 I wanted a 2nd login, not a different account. I only had 1 login before and wanted a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to pay any attention to them at all - they go away as soon as you have typed the new password twice.

I agree, the old style was less intrusive, but it looks like the preferred graphic style is now for the big red blocks, so I don't think this is a password screen issue, but a general UI issue.