# Yes, I know my passwords do not match, I'm still typing them!

Tags: bug, sign-up

This picture shows me typing in my confirmation password when I sign up:

[image]

My response? Yes, I know my passwords do not match, I'm still typing them!

Why does this show all the time, and not just after you have clicked off the box, if they don't match?

Or, an alternative solution:

> Maybe they should only show if they match or not, once the second password's length is >= to the first password's length.
>
> -- [Roombatron5000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251741/yes-i-know-my-passwords-do-not-match-im-still-typing-them#comment822086_251741)

Another solution:

> Or do what some sites do: background red in the second box until/unless they match. Then it's not obtrusive but is easy to implement.
>
> --[Joe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251741/yes-i-know-my-passwords-do-not-match-im-still-typing-them#comment822089_251741)

UX links:

[Telling users passwords don't match and aren't strong enough](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35304/telling-users-passwords-dont-match-and-arent-strong-enough)

[When registering should the passwords match/don't match still be shown if the initial password isn't strong enough](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41972/when-registering-should-the-passwords-match-dont-match-still-be-shown-if-the-in)

[When should I validate that the password in a confirmation field matches the first password entered?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/67541/when-should-i-validate-that-the-password-in-a-confirmation-field-matches-the-fir)

Comment: Or do what some sites do: background red in the second box until/unless they match.  Then it's not obtrusive but is easy to implement.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218162/please-do-not-bother-me-about-password-mismatches-until-ive-finished-typing?rq=1 (Same happens with registration forms)

Comment: This is the registration forms. Although this is a little different - it's the new new login page!

Comment: @James forgot to tag ^^

Comment: Yeah, just making a note that it's not just one form - ie if this is proposal is implemented then might be worth doing a clean sweep across the board.

Comment: Ahh I see, yes, I agree.

Comment: Please don't flood the front page with edits

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273213/adding-a-link-with-a-space-in-front-causes-the-link-to-not-work#comment1105103_273213

Answer (score 1):

Seems reasonable to show message first time only after `blur` event.

But then (if they didn't match) I actually would prefer message to be rechecked on every `input` after I return into the field. You can try it in a snippet:

```js
~function () {
  var a = document.getElementById('a'), b = document.getElementById('b')
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg')

  function updateValidity() {
    msg.hidden = a.value === b.value
  }

  b.addEventListener('blur', function onBlur(e) {
    updateValidity()

    b.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur)

    a.addEventListener('input', updateValidity)
    b.addEventListener('input', updateValidity)
  })
}()
```

```html
<p><input type=password id=a>
<p><input type=password id=b> <span id=msg hidden>Passwords don't match</span>
```

And about proposal with checking length - it's a bad idea as I can just miss a char when entering the second value. I have to know they didn't match in that case too.